# how to crossfade div along with image by jquery

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I have following structure:

```
<div id="container">
<img src="http://webaddress/firstimage.png" alt="1stimage" />
<img src="http://webaddress/secondimage.png" alt="2ndimage" />
<img src="http://webaddress/thirdimage.png" alt="3rdimage" />
</div>
```

I crossfade images by following jquery code:

```
$('#container img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){$('#container :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#container');}, 3000);
```

and the css is:

```
#container{
position: relative;
float:left;
margin-top: 7px;
}
#container img{position:absolute;}
```

But I want to crossfade divs instead just images because I may have images with a short description like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="1stimg">
   <img src="http://webaddress/firstimage.png" alt="1stimage" />
   <p>This is the first image</p>
  </div>
  <div id="2ndimg">
   <img src="http://webaddress/secondimage.png" alt="2ndimage" />
   <p>This is the second image</p>
  </div>
  <div id="3rdimg">
   <img src="http://webaddress/thirdimage.png" alt="3rdimage" />
   <p>This is the third & last image</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I do that?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance